# wordpress with multiple members and its roles

Tags: wordpress

Hi can anybody let me know how we can implement the multiple user roles in wordpress along with restriction of the pages or posts and other part which would be only for a particular role. and Staff user can login and see its emails and reply to them as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Free plugin "User Roles and Capabilities". The plugins URL is given below.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities